# Android List disappear after intent back to activity

Tags: android

I have a CreateReceiptActivity and also QRScan activity, after intent to QR Scan and intent back to CreateReceiptActivity. The list or receipt item becomes empty again ( if I already add item to the list, after that I want to add item again using QR Scan, the item in the list becomes empty again). Can somebody help me with this issue ?

[image: illustration]

here's the code

```
public class CreateReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.receipt_date)
    TextView date;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_invoice)
    TextView invoiceNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_add_item)
    ImageButton addItem;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_print)
    ImageButton printItem;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_view_recycler)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.create_receipt_pb_loading)
    ProgressBar pbloading;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    List<ListAutoComplete> autoCompleteList;
    ListAutoComplete listAutoComplete;


    List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemList;
    ListReceiptItem listReceiptItem;
    ArrayList temporaryList;
    ReceiptItemAdapter adapter;
    public String itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, itemDate, itemInvoice, lastInvoice, qrResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_receipt);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        receiptItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(this, receiptItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString();
        itemDate = setDate(date);
        date.setText(this.getString(R.string.date, setDate(date)));

        printItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                pbloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                cutStock();
                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                Builder builder = new Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Print Transaksi ?").setPositiveButton("Ya", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Tidak", dialogClickListener).show();

            }
        });
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null && extras .containsKey("QRItemtype")){
            qrResult = extras.getString("QRItemtype");
            if (qrResult == null) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Scan gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (!(qrResult == null)) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, qrResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openDialog();

            }
        });

    }

    private void cutStock() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        for (ListReceiptItem listreceiptItem : receiptItemList) {
            final String soldItemDate = date.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemtype = listreceiptItem.getType();
            final String soldItemQty = listreceiptItem.getQty();
            final String soldItemPrice = listreceiptItem.getPrice();

            db.collection("watchlist").whereEqualTo("type", soldItemtype)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                            String id = document.getString("id");
                            String oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(oldqty) - Integer.parseInt(soldItemQty);
                            String newQty = String.valueOf(i);

                            Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("qty", newQty);
                            db.collection("watchlist").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());

                            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            Map<String, Object> receiptItem = new HashMap<>();
                            receiptItem.put("invoice", soldItemInvoice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("date", soldItemDate);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("type", soldItemtype);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("qty", soldItemQty);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("price", soldItemPrice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);


                            final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("sales").add(receiptItem).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Berhasil mencetak transaksi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(soldItemInvoice) + 1;
                                    String newInvoice = String.valueOf(i);
                                    invoiceNumber.setText(newInvoice);
                                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Gagal mencetak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        openDialog();
    }
    private void openDialog(){
        LayoutInflater li = CreateReceiptActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_create_receipt, null);
        final Builder builder = new Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
        builder.setView(v);
        final EditText addItemType = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_type);
        final EditText addItemQty = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_qty);
        final EditText addItemPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_price);
        Button btnSubmit = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_submit);
        addItemType.setText(qrResult);


        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                Button btnScan = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_scanqr);
                btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(CreateReceiptActivity.this, QRScannerActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(i, QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();



        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                itemType = addItemType.getText().toString().trim();
                itemQty = addItemQty.getText().toString().trim();
                itemPrice = addItemPrice.getText().toString().trim();
                listReceiptItem = new ListReceiptItem(itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, "0");
                receiptItemList.add(listReceiptItem);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                qrResult = null;
                Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "barang tertambah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void getTypeList() {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference documentReference = db.collection("watchlist");
        documentReference.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                                String type = document.getString("type");
                                listAutoComplete = new ListAutoComplete(type);
                                autoCompleteList.add(listAutoComplete);
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public String setDate(TextView view) {

        java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();//getting date
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");//formating according to my need
        String date = formatter.format(today);
        view.setText(date);
        return date;
    }



}
```

This is my QRScan activity:

```
public class QRScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //View Objects
    private String itemTypeQR;

    //qr code scanner object
    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrscanner_activity);

        //intializing scan object
        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        qrScan.setOrientationLocked(false);
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }

    //Getting the scan results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                finish();
            } else {
                //if qr contains data
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    //setting values to textviews
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    itemTypeQR = obj.getString("type");
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    finish();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this,CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //initiating the qr code scan
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi can you please post your QRScanActivity code. so i can answer it.

Comment: Hi Justin, have you used the `saveInstanceState()` and `onRestore()` methods to save the details in a bundle, it looks like only the UI is affected...

Comment: @android I already edit and add the QR Scan activity

Comment: @varun I haven't use it. I'm still new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first make your ListReceiptItem implements Parcelable like below:

```
public class ListReceiptItem implements Parcelable {
      // please keep your methods and variables here as it is
}
```

Don't forget to write "writeToParcel" method in your ListReceiptItem class and below is only example of "writeToParcel" method. you have to google it if you doesn't know about Parcelable.

```
@Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.grade);
   }
```

Then copy paste below two classes as it is because i have just edited it where it passes list from QRScannerActivity to CreateReceiptActivity and after adding items from CreateReceiptActivity it will return that list in QRScannerActivity and we can found it in onActivityResult() of QRScannerActivity. Also don't call finish() after startActivityForResult().

> QRScannerActivity

```
public class QRScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //View Objects
    private String itemTypeQR;

    //qr code scanner object
    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    // newly added
    List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemList = new List<ListReceiptItem>;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrscanner_activity);

        //intializing scan object
        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        qrScan.setOrientationLocked(false);
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }

    //Getting the scan results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(data != null && data.getExtras() != null){
                List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemListNew = (List<ListReceiptItem>) bundle.getParcelable("mList");
                if(receiptItemListNew != null){
                    receiptItemList.clear();
                    receiptItemList.addAll(receiptItemListNew);
                }
            }
        }
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                qrResult.putParcelable("mList", receiptItemList);
                startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);

            } else {
                //if qr contains data
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    //setting values to textviews
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    itemTypeQR = obj.getString("type");
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    qrResult.putParcelable("mList", receiptItemList);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this,CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    qrResult.putParcelable("mList", receiptItemList);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);

                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //initiating the qr code scan
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

> CreateReceiptActivity

```
public class CreateReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.receipt_date)
    TextView date;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_invoice)
    TextView invoiceNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_add_item)
    ImageButton addItem;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_print)
    ImageButton printItem;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_view_recycler)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.create_receipt_pb_loading)
    ProgressBar pbloading;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    List<ListAutoComplete> autoCompleteList;
    ListAutoComplete listAutoComplete;


    List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemList = new List<ListReceiptItem>;
    ListReceiptItem listReceiptItem;
    ReceiptItemAdapter adapter;
    public String itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, itemDate, itemInvoice, lastInvoice, qrResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_receipt);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().contains("mList")){
            receiptItemList.clear();
            receiptItemList.addAll((List<ListReceiptItem>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableExtra("mList"));
        }

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(this, receiptItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString();
        itemDate = setDate(date);
        date.setText(this.getString(R.string.date, setDate(date)));

        printItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                pbloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                cutStock();
                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Print Transaksi ?").setPositiveButton("Ya", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Tidak", dialogClickListener).show();

            }
        });


        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater li = CreateReceiptActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

                final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_create_receipt, null);
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setView(v);
                final EditText addItemType = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_type);
                final EditText addItemQty = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_qty);
                final EditText addItemPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_price);
                Button btnSubmit = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_submit);


                final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        Button btnScan = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_scanqr);
                        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(CreateReceiptActivity.this, QRScannerActivity.class);
                                i.putParcelable("mList", receiptItemList);
                                startActivityForResult(i, QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        itemType = addItemType.getText().toString().trim();
                        itemQty = addItemQty.getText().toString().trim();
                        itemPrice = addItemPrice.getText().toString().trim();
                        listReceiptItem = new ListReceiptItem(itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, "0");
                        receiptItemList.add(listReceiptItem);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "barang tertambah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        } else if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    qrResult = extras.getString("QRItemtype");
                if (qrResult == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scan gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(qrResult == null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, qrResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void cutStock() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        for (ListReceiptItem listreceiptItem : receiptItemList) {
            final String soldItemDate = date.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemtype = listreceiptItem.getType();
            final String soldItemQty = listreceiptItem.getQty();
            final String soldItemPrice = listreceiptItem.getPrice();

            db.collection("watchlist").whereEqualTo("type", soldItemtype)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                            String id = document.getString("id");
                            String oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(oldqty) - Integer.parseInt(soldItemQty);
                            String newQty = String.valueOf(i);

                            Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("qty", newQty);
                            db.collection("watchlist").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());

                            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            Map<String, Object> receiptItem = new HashMap<>();
                            receiptItem.put("invoice", soldItemInvoice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("date", soldItemDate);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("type", soldItemtype);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("qty", soldItemQty);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("price", soldItemPrice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);


                            final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("sales").add(receiptItem).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Berhasil mencetak transaksi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(soldItemInvoice) + 1;
                                    String newInvoice = String.valueOf(i);
                                    invoiceNumber.setText(newInvoice);
                                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Gagal mencetak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void getTypeList() {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference documentReference = db.collection("watchlist");
        documentReference.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                                String type = document.getString("type");
                                listAutoComplete = new ListAutoComplete(type);
                                autoCompleteList.add(listAutoComplete);
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public String setDate(TextView view) {

        java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();//getting date
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");//formating according to my need
        String date = formatter.format(today);
        view.setText(date);
        return date;
    }

}
```

Comment: this line has an error receiptItemList.addAll(List<ListReceiptItem>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableExtra("mList");

Comment: it has the red wave below the text on addAll(List<ListReceiptItem>)

Comment: oops! i have just forgot to put ) at end of the line. because we have to cast it. i have edited my answer for CreateReceiptActivity. please refer it again!